# SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy using enums as discriminator value

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, enums

Is it possible to use an enum as a discriminator value when using SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy?

Answer (score 65):

If what you are trying to achieve is to not to duplicate the discriminator values, there is a simple workaround.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="FREQUENCY",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)    
public abstract class Event  {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value=Frequency.Values.WEEKLY)
public class WeeklyEvent extends Event {
    …
}

public enum Frequency {
    DAILY(Values.DAILY),
    WEEKLY(Values.WEEKLY),
    MONTHLY(Values.MONTHLY);
    
    private String value;

    …

    public static class Values {
        public static final String DAILY = "D";
        public static final String WEEKLY = "W";
        public static final String MONTHLY = "M";
    }   
}
```

Nothing to do with Hibernate/JPA really, but better than having to maintain the values in multiple places.

Answer (score 29):

I just wanted to improve the great answer of @asa about the workaround. Usually, we often like to use the discriminator column as an attribute of the abstract class, and mapped with an `enum` of course. We can still use the solution mentioned above and force some consistencies between `enum` names (used to map the column) and `String` values (used as discrimnator values). Here is my suggestion:

```
public enum ELanguage {
  JAVA(Values.JAVA), GROOVY(Values.GROOVY);

  private ELanguage (String val) {
     // force equality between name of enum instance, and value of constant
     if (!this.name().equals(val))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect use of ELanguage");
  }

  public static class Values {
     public static final String JAVA= "JAVA";
     public static final String GROOVY= "GROOVY";
  }
}
```

And for the entities, here is the code:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="LANGUAGE_TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)    
public abstract class Snippet {
   // update/insert is managed by discriminator mechanics
   @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_TYPE", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) 
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   public ELanguage languageType
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value=ELanguage.Values.JAVA)
public class JavaSnippet extends Snippet {
    …
}
```

Still not perfect, but a little bit better, I think.

Comment: The languageType field is null when retrieved from the entity manager so this is not working for me.

Comment: @dukethrash it will be hard to help you without more details. Maybe a fiddle ? Did you checked the column in database ?

Answer (score 8):

No, unfortunately you can't.

If you try to use an enum as discriminator value, you'll get a Type Mismatch exception ("cannot convert from MyEnum to String"), as the only discriminator types allowed are String, Char and Integer. 
Next, I tried using an enum's name and ordinal combined with DiscriminatorType.STRING and DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, respectively. But this didn't work either, as the @DiscriminatorValue annotation (as any other) requires a constant expression:

This doesn't work:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="FREQUENCY",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)    
public abstract class Event  {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value=Frequency.WEEKLY.name())
public class WeeklyEvent extends Event {
    // Exception: The value for annotation attribute DiscriminatorValue.value must be a constant expression
}
```

Doesn't work either:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="FREQUENCY",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER
) 
public abstract class Event  {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value=Frequency.WEEKLY.ordinal())
public class WeeklyEvent extends Event {
    // Exception: The value for annotation attribute DiscriminatorValue.value must be a constant expression
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to invert the relationship: define the discriminator value as a constant in the entity, then wrap it in the enum:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name = "FIELD_TYPE",
    discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
public class Shape {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(Square.DISCRIMINATOR_VALUE)
public class Square extends Shape {
    public static final String DISCRIMINATOR_VALUE = "SQUARE";
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(Circle.DISCRIMINATOR_VALUE)
public class Circle extends Shape {
    public static final String DISCRIMINATOR_VALUE = "CIRCLE";
}

@AllArgsConstructor
public enum FieldType {
    SHAPE(Shape.DISCRIMINATOR_VALUE),
    CIRCLE(Circle.DISCRIMINATOR_VALUE);

    @Getter
    private final String discriminatorValue;
}
```

Apart from eliminating duplication, this code is also less tightly coupled: entity classes don't depend on enum values and can be added without having to change other code; while the enum can "enumerate" different classes from different sources - depending on the context where it is used.

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge, this is not possible with annotations:

- discriminator value must be of type `String`
- discriminator value must be a compile-time-constant, i.e. return values from methods on enums are not allowed.

Comment: JPA 2.1 hasn't changed this?

Comment: It's not JPA, the Java language does not allow you to call methods for annotation values, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7 at 9.7.1, read the list: "The type of `V` is assignment compatible (§5.2) with `T`, and furthermore:". So `MyEnum.ENUM_CONST.x()` is invalid, `MyEnum.ENUM_CONST` would be valid, but `T` is `String` here.

Answer (score 3):

yup ,when you define discriminator the annotation's option are name and discrimatorType

```
@DiscriminatorColumn (name="MYDISCRIMINATOR", discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
```

of which DiscriminatorType can only be:

```
DiscriminatorType.STRING
DiscriminatorType.CHAR
DiscriminatorType.INTEGER
```

unfortunate I didn't see this yesterday but well. That's the way it is

Comment: And note that `DiscriminatorType` refers to the DB type and not the Java type. `DiscriminatorValue` must still have a number in quotes as a String.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DiscriminatorType.INTEGER`, and map each subclass with `@DiscriminatorValue("X")`, where `X` must be the ordinal value of the enum (0,1,2,3...).

It **must** be the value *as a constant String*. You can't use `YourEnum.SOME_VALUE.ordinal()`, because annotation attribute values must be constants. Yes, it is tedious. Yes, it is error-prone. But it works.

Comment: This is a hacky workaround, however it works, I'd put huge comments in an `enum` which is used as a `DiscriminatorValue`! Also the same works with enum names (with `DiscriminatorType.String` which may be more stable than the ordinal.