# Using SINGLE_TABLE inheritance with Rest Repositories

Tags: spring-data-rest, single-table-inheritance

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="vehicletype", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class AbstractVehicle {
...

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = VehicleTypes.Values.Car)
public class Car extends AbstractVehicle {
...

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractVehicleRepository<T extends AbstractVehicle> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, Long> {
...

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel="cars", path="cars")
public interface CarRepository extends AbstractVehicleRepository<Car> {
...
```

(discriminator values are constants within enums as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639225/single-table-inheritance-strategy-using-enums-as-discriminator-value))

Running against a MySQL database.

I can start my Spring Boot application, but when I try to access the REST URL `/cars`, I get an exception complaining that the `abstract_vehicle` table doesn't exist.

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.1 on a MySQL database, with the Spring Starts for Security, Web, Data-Rest, Hal-Browser and Data-Jpa in my dependencies.

Is `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance compatible with Spring Data Rest Repositories? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens if you bypass SDR and just get the data from the repo? (in like a unit test)