# @DiscriminatorValue Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to String

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

Though I defined the parent class to use discriminator column of Type Integer, the compiler keeps giving error : `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to String` for child class using Integer discriminator value

```
@Table(name="ITEMS")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="ITEM_CATEGORY",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public class Item { ....}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value=ItemCategory.Values.LEARNING_DUTY)
public class LearningDuty extends Item {...}


public static class Values {
        
        public static final Integer LEARNING_DUTY = 3;

    }
```

pom file:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I tried cleaning the project and rebuilding, restarting the IDE, but issue persists
I am using STS 4

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question:? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639225/single-table-inheritance-strategy-using-enums-as-discriminator-value

Comment: @tashkhisi, unfortunately no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is a statically typed language. So `discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER` cannot change the type of `DiscriminatorValue`'s `value`.

[It's explained e.g. here](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/3.1.0/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_mapping_discrim.html):

> The `DiscriminatorValue` annotation specifies the discriminator value
> for each class. Though this annotation's value is always a string, the
> implementation will parse it according to the `DiscriminatorColumn`'s
> `discriminatorType` property above.

Therefore you have to specify the discriminator value as follows:

```
@DiscriminatorValue(value=""+ItemCategory.Values.LEARNING_DUTY)
```